# sha1sum in wikipedia dump

Tags: sha1, wikipedia

does anyone know how the sha1 sum in wikipedia dumps is build? I just found: "These contain information like the sha1 sum of each revision text..." 
(http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Dump_format)

But when I try to calculate the sum of any revision text, I never get the same sum. So I thought maybe there is something more influencing this value. I took all the text between the "text"-tags.
Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to decode any XML character entities (like `&lt;` or `&amp;`) in the page text before feeding it to SHA-1? Also, the SHA-1 hash is computed from the raw UTF-8 encoded bytes of the page text, as it's stored in the database. Converting it to some other encoding, or otherwise mangling it (e.g. doing any Unicode character normalization) is likely change the hash value.

Comment: I opened the xml-dump in sublime text and just copied out the text blocks. I saw no xml-chars in this block. I did the same with firefox. The sha1 sum was the same in both ways. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Hmm, it could be a whitespace issue; changing the newlines from LF to CR+LF (or vice versa) could change the hash, for example.

Comment: Could you add a specific example? On which article did you try this and what was the SHA1 you got?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post an example. They all have links in it and stackoverflow says: I have to less reputations (need at least 10) to post two links and they all have links in it. But I used this dump: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140402/enwiki-20140402-pages-meta-history17.xml-p007522354p007524997.7z and the first article in it (Njala University). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: 1) Do you take into account that these hashes are converted into base36? 2) Verify that nothing's mangling UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sha1sum is converted from an hex- to a base36-number and it is just the revisiontext between the `<text></text>` -tags. Thanks to MaxSem!